# Java Set как ключ в хэше

Tags: java

Необходимо создать hashmap в котором ключом будет Set (реализация неважна). Проблема в том, что в существующих реализациях хэш вычисляется как сумма хэшей элементов. Но нужна устойчивая функция хэширования. Помогите ее найти.

Comment: возможно передать сэт в другую коллекцию, но она должна обладать устойчивым hashCode()

Comment: А смысл? Если сильно хочется, можете использовать например `IdentityHashMap`. Но все-равно непонятно, какую проблему вы решаете.

Comment: @a_gura задача у меня более общая : в одном методе происходит частое создание класса (тяжеловесного), параметром конструктора служит сэт. Я хочу создать кэш (guava cache) , который будет кэшировать этот класс, ключом должен быть сэт. 
PS других аргументов для ключа кэша нет. Необходимость кэширования оправдана

Comment: Почему вас не устраивает стандартная реализация `hashCode` в `Set`? Зачем вам устойчивость? Если ваш ключ меняется, то, как мне кажется, любая хэшфункция, которая не зависит от состояния `Set` будет некорректной. Кроме того, изменение состояния ключа в `Map` чревато последствиями.

Если все же `Set` должен изменяться, то единственное, что приходт в голову сходу, это перед изменениям множества, удалять его из кэша.

Comment: @a_gura я имел ввиду, что 2 разных сета могут промапится в один вэлью

Comment: Но ведь так и должно быть при условии эквивалентности всех элементов этого сета.

Comment: @a_gura приведу пример.  Пришлел сет с хэшем А,  пришел второй сет с неэквивалентными элементами, но с хэшем тоже А. Тогда кэш вернет неверные данные

Comment: Неверно. Если элементы равны по хэшу, то в дело вступает `equals`.

Comment: @a_gura так я и говорю, что мы можем получить неравные по хэшу элементы, но (вспоминая, что хэш сета - это N умножить на сумму хэшей внутри) может произойти, что суммы совпадут. Тогда из кэша мы достанем значение не то.

Comment: @a_gura мы ведь вычисляем хэш перед тем как обратиться к кэшу за значением по ключу.  Окажется, что одинаковый ключ для разных сэтов

Comment: Да, хэш будет одинаковый. Все, что это значит, это то, что разные сеты окажутся в одном списке. Затем все-равно будет произведено сравнение по `equals`, что позволит получить правильный сет. См. как устроен `HashMap` для примера.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать POJO?